# Logging Closures and non Sinatra classes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, sinatra, closures

I am new to Ruby and Sinatra and trying to access [logger](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Logging) object inside closures (`EM.run do .. end`).

Here is extracts from working code where logging statements with messagge "LOGGER IS NOT ACCESSIBLE HERE" give compilation error.

```
class Connection
  def get_updates
   logger.info "LOGGER IS NOT ACCESSIBLE HERE 1"
  end
end

class Streamer < Sinatra::Base
  def stream
    logger.info "Inside stream"
    EM.run do
     logger.info "LOGGER IS NOT ACCESSIBLE HERE 3"
     Connection.new.get_updates

     EM::PeriodicTimer.new(10) do
      logger.info "LOGGER IS NOT ACCESSIBLE HERE 4"
     end
   end
  end
end
get '/' do
  logger.info "loading data"
  Streamer.new.stream  
end
```

From the [document](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Logging) I found Sinatra uses `env['rack.logger']`. How can we use same in non Sinatra classes like Connection and Streamer in above code?

Answer (score 1):

Actually a very interesting question. As it turns out, the `logger` field is not actually a variable - it is a method within `Sinatra::Base`. So when you are executing code that is in the scope of a `Sinatra::Base` object, you can call `logger` by just typing it and it will return you the logger object.

Since it's a part of the `Sinatra::Base` object, it won't be visible within the scope of a `Connection` object.

Now we're ending the simple Ruby stuff, time for the more advanced bit.

The more interesting part is when you call it from within the `EM.run do` section. The reason that you can't use logger in there is because those blocks are *not* executed within the scope of the `Streamer` object, they are executed in some other scope by eventmachine itself using something like `instance_eval` or `class_eval` - [this post](http://www.trottercashion.com/2011/02/08/rubys-define_method-method_missing-and-instance_eval.html) shows a good example of how `instance_eval` works in a DSL like EM.

This is also why the `logger` method is accessible from the `get '/'` block - Sinatra will execute this block in the scope of an object that has a `logger` method using `instance_eval`.

In order to do what you want to do, you can try creating a local variable containing the logger:

```
class Streamer < Sinatra::Base
  def stream
    # This will create a local variable called logger that will
    # save whatever is returned by the logger method
    logger = self.logger

    logger.info "Inside stream"
    EM.run do
     logger.info "This should now be accessible"
     Connection.new.get_updates

     EM::PeriodicTimer.new(10) do
      logger.info "This should now be accessible"
     end
   end
  end
end
```

This still doesn't solve the problem of logging from within your `Connection` class. The way to do that would be to either use a global log variable (bad idea) or pass in the logger variable when you do `Connection.new` (not amazing idea, but better than a global).